# Animate 1-parameter family of parametric surfaces in Manim

Tags: manim

I know how to plot a parametric surface using Manim. How can I plot (or rather animate) a whole 1-parameter family of parametric surfaces? For instance, the deformation of a sphere into an ellipsoid

```
(t,u,v) -> [(1+t)sin(u)cos(v),(1+2t)sin(u)sin(v),(1+3t)cos(u)]
```

as t ranges from, say 0 to 1.

Comment: Do you actually need to animate this specific transformation, or can you just use the transform function between a sphere and an ellipsoid?